# Resizing UIImageView without scaling UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, cgsize

I have a `UIImageView` that display a `UIImage` with the content mode set with `UIContentModeScaleAspectFit`. The imageview is as width as the screen. I want to resize the imageview without changing image position and scale. So, after resizing, the UIImage would be still virtually at the same position and still virtually as width as the screen, but not entirely visible because of the imageview resizing.

I try using `UIContentModeLeft`, while resizing from the right, to fix `UIImage` position, but my image wasn't at full resolution like when I'm using `UIContentModeScaleAspectFit`.

I'm clueless about this. I might need to use CGImage or CIImage, but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve my problem. Here's what I did :

- Create a `UIView` in which I add a `UIImageView` subview
- Set the imageview content mode to `UIContentModeScaleAspectFit`
- Defining imageview frame to the screen with `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]`
- `setClipsToBounds = YES` to the `UIView`

Now, when resizing, the imageview is not scaling because its frame is define to be as big as the screen, `setClipsToBounds:` make sure I don't see part of the image that is outside of the UIView frame.

Answer (score 1):

Set the image you want to display as the background of the view, instead of the source image.

You can use:

`yourImageView.background = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nameOfTheImageYouWantToDisplay"]];`

Comment: It's not working as expected. When setting the image as the bactkground, the image is much larger than the screen and I only see a small part. That's  why I initially want to use UIContentModeScaleAspectFit. Otherwise, I need to use a much lower image resolution, like 375px width on an iPhone 6 to fit the screen... But that was a good idea, for a moment I thought it would solve my issue.